# WiFi calling with 1st SIM number using cellular data of 2nd SIM?

Tags: google-pixel, dual-sim, wifi-calling

Does Android support WiFi calling using cellular data of 2nd SIM?

When I travel I don't want to use the pricey roaming for my home SIM card (first), but I would like to make and receive call with my home number. I usually get a local sim card (second) and use it as data SIM card.

It would be perfect to use cellular data from second SIM card to make calls (travel/local) with first SIM card (home).

I'm using a Google Pixel, but I'm asking in general for Android.

Comment: I'm really not an expert, but my guess is it's not really possible to link the 1st SIM to the 2nd SIM in terms of their own mobile network, regardless of Google Pixel or even Android... but hopefully someone can prove me wrong.